# python iterating strings

Tags: python, string, file

I am writing the content of "article" to a text file.

Source file:

```
lol hi
lol hello
lol text
lol test
```

Python:

```
for line in all_lines:
    if line.startswith('lol '):
        mystring = line.replace('lol ', '').lower().rstrip()

article = 'this is my saved file\n' + mystring + '\nthe end'
```

This is what gets saved to the txt file:

```
this is my saved file
test
the end
```

This is what I want saved to the txt file:

```
this is the saved file
hi
hello
test
text
the end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are replacing the string each time. You will want to store the results of each `lol` line and then add them all to `mystring`:

```
mystring = []
for line in all_lines:
    if line.startswith('lol '):
        mystring.append(line.replace('lol ', '', 1).lower().rstrip() + '\n')

article = 'this is my saved file\n'+''.join(mystring)+'\nthe end'
```

In the above code, I've turned `mystring` into list which is then turned into a string at the end using the [`join`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method. Note that I've added a newline (`\n`) character to each line as you want that character in your output (and [`rstrip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) removes it). Alternatively, you can write:

```
line.replace('lol ', '', 1).lower().rstrip(' ')
```

which lets `rstrip()` only strip spaces and not all other forms of whitespace.

---

**Edit**: An alternative approach is to write:

```
mystring.append(line.replace('lol ', '').lower().rstrip())
```

and:

```
article = 'this is my saved file\n'+'\n'.join(mystring)+'\nthe end'
```

Comment: `replace` is a little dangerous here; `replace('lol ','', 1)` would prevent the possibility of an unintentional second replacement.

Comment: @SimeonVisser -- I deleted my comment because it was incorrect.  But I'm glad you added that alternative.  (it's more clear to me anyway).

Comment: @mgilson: Why is it incorrect? Each line (except the last) will get a `\n` using `join()` and the last line will get it as well from `'\nthe end'`. Of course, it is not platform-independent code...

Comment: @SimeonVisser -- your answer is completely correct.  It was my comment which was wrong. (hence my deleting it).

Comment: You could do this with one generator: `'this is my saved file\n' + ''.join(line.replace('lol ', '').lower() for line in all_lines if line.startswith('lol ')) + 'the end'`

Answer (score 0):

... or as a one-liner,

```
mystring = ''.join(line[4:].lower() for line in all_lines if line.startswith('lol '))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take this different approach:

```
with open('test.txt') as fin, open('out.txt', 'w') as fout:
    fout.write('this is my saved file\n')
    for line in fin:
        if line.startswith('lol '):
            fout.write(line.replace('lol ', '').lower())
    fout.write('the end')
```